# Double Delete(?) In Binary Search Trees

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am writing a code that tests if two binary search trees are equal.

However whenever I'm deallocating memory I am having an access violation error. Going through it, I saw that I'm accessing the memory address 0xfeefee on my deallocation function. I am getting the access violation in the Cell destructor function.

Also I realy don't know if this function works, however I'm not really asking help for that -- though help will still be appreciated.

Deallocation function:

```
~Cell(void) {
    if (left) { delete left; }
    if (right) { delete right; }
}
```

Function:

```
bool BST::isEqualTo(const BST& that) const{
    if(root <= 0 && that.root <= 0){
        return true;
    }else if(root <= 0 || that.root <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    if(root->val != that.root->val){
        false;
    }
    /*Cell* saved_node1 = new Cell(*root);
    Cell* saved_node2 = new Cell(*that.root);*/
    BST a, b, c, d;
    a.root = root->left;
    b.root = that.root->left;
    c.root = root->right;
    d.root = that.root->right;
    if(a.isEqualTo(b) && c.isEqualTo(d)){
        /*a.root = saved_node1;
        b.root = saved_node2;
        c.root = saved_node1;
        d.root = saved_node2;*/
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Tree destructor:

```
void BST::destroy(void) {
    length = 0;
    delete root;
    root = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The type of `BST::root` variable is `Cell*`, am I right? Also, show `~BST`, please.

Comment: yes root is a Cell* datatype.

Comment: @user2280704: Can you show BST destructor, please?

Comment: the destructor just calls the destroy function I've posted above.

Comment: This problem is usually caused because you have not implemented the rule of three.

Comment: @LokiAstari, care to mention them?

Comment: [The Rule of Three](http://bit.ly/17PhUcz) as it pertains to C++. There ya go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in this part of code

```
BST a, b, c, d;
a.root = root->left;
b.root = that.root->left;
c.root = root->right;
d.root = that.root->right;
```

You create `BST` objects, which will be destroyed as soon as the function finishes. And after it all memory, allocated for `root` pointers will be freed.

I suggest you to write another compare function like this:

```
bool _is_equal(Cell* c1, Cell* c2)
{
    if(c1 == nullptr && c2 == nullptr)
        return true;
    else if(c1 == nullptr || c2 == nullptr)
        return false;

    return  (c1 -> val == c2 -> val) &&
            _is_equal(c1 -> left,  c2 -> left) &&
            _is_equal(c1 -> right, c2 -> right);
}
```

And call it in your function

```
bool BST::isEqualTo(const BST& that) const
{
    return _is_equal(root, that.root);
}
```

And, of course, you should overload `operator==` to compare two objects. It will look more pretty.

Comment: I see. Should I then make a copy (newly allocated memory) of the root->left and root->right?

Comment: @user2280704 Don't make a copy. The comparison should not require volatility at all, and honestly should not require temporary BST's. You have a function that compares from the cell down (two cells, and if they match, then their kids respectively). Exploit that, and only that. No temp BSTs needed. See soon's code above in the cell-comparator. just fire that against your two BST's root cell pointers. (and +1 on this answer, btw.)